# Greek letters and subscripts in histogram titles of a `pairs` plot matrix

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I got [a great answer a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733618/hacking-the-plot-data-frame-method-in-r-to-include-histograms-on-the-diagonals-a/29734548#29734548) about how to customize the `pairs` function, but I need to merge it with `expression` and I'm not sure how to do so within the framework of the answer given.

The dummy example:

```
N=1000
x1 = rgamma(N,5,10)
x2 = rnorm(N)+x1
x3 = (x1+x2)/(runif(N)+1)
d = data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
plot(d,col=rgb(1,0,0,.5),pch=19,cex=.5)
```

I was looking for lowess lines and histograms, which the previous answerer did with the following:

```
panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
    h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
    breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
    y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
    rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, ...)
}
panel.loess<-function(x, y, ...) {
    ll <- loess(y~x)
    points(x,y, ...)
    nx<-seq(min(x), max(x), length.out=100)
    lines(nx, predict(ll, nx), col="black")

}


pairs(d,col=rgb(1,0,0,.5),pch=19,cex=.5, 
   diag.panel=panel.hist, 
   lower.panel=panel.loess)
```

[image]

Now I want to put sub/superscripts and greek letters in the titles.  If I was just calling `main = 'whatever'`, I'd do `expression(paste(hat('pr'),delta['t-1'],sep=''))`.  Given that this isn't a character string, I cant just add a character vector argument to `panel.hist`

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the titles"? The text in the panels on the diagonal?

Comment: Yeah, that.  Manually would be `title("title",line=-2)` or something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1384349/489704 (i.e. pass a vector of expressions to the `labels` arg of `pairs`)

Comment: Yeah, it does.  Hurr durr.  Thanks.